# ActiveStorage gets stuck in recursive attachment create and destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to attach a js file to a model and store in s3 but every time I run the attach method with file io objects, the server gets hung up in a recursive create and delete of the activestorage attachment database as you can see in these server logs:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "p7bq76rurim77iao2r9a01pj0pwg"], ["filename", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c.js"], ["content_type", "application/javascript"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "amazon"], ["byte_size", 13], ["checksum", "XY+qICmXk3H4sx9RJIwiMA=="], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.911872"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "js_file"], ["record_type", "Property"], ["record_id", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c"], ["blob_id", "e96f2305-a7dd-4e81-b4be-95e8c8d00df5"], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.917626"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = $1  [["id", "b705726b-b97d-47d6-bb70-de0c9d4dfa6b"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "zybcvyig2o0u7dgogisklfnig7xv"], ["filename", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c.js"], ["content_type", "application/javascript"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "amazon"], ["byte_size", 13], ["checksum", "XY+qICmXk3H4sx9RJIwiMA=="], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.944469"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "js_file"], ["record_type", "Property"], ["record_id", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c"], ["blob_id", "23e176a4-3816-47fe-97a5-e2bb3af97a1d"], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.947629"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = $1  [["id", "7d0e1765-4d6a-46ed-8b29-012adecda684"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "8997y96c81r8fxcofbe854ivu2r1"], ["filename", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c.js"], ["content_type", "application/javascript"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "amazon"], ["byte_size", 13], ["checksum", "XY+qICmXk3H4sx9RJIwiMA=="], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.965508"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "js_file"], ["record_type", "Property"], ["record_id", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c"], ["blob_id", "4646e337-2ae3-4afc-aab0-48f84af4657d"], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.969796"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (2.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = $1  [["id", "c687a1fa-7ba3-4e76-af20-a3867c153b95"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "83hcoeo5mdwo4glg3gjmb7jx2l34"], ["filename", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c.js"], ["content_type", "application/javascript"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "amazon"], ["byte_size", 13], ["checksum", "XY+qICmXk3H4sx9RJIwiMA=="], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:54.998981"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "js_file"], ["record_type", "Property"], ["record_id", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c"], ["blob_id", "9e053cf2-a248-44b9-bf37-b3005efea1be"], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:55.004691"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = $1  [["id", "5bc44cce-62cf-4dc5-829e-97dfd9b28411"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "a4c22dupjyndviedp41r6e8cg7dx"], ["filename", "c520252d-a889-4636-ad9c-30973429e25c.js"], ["content_type", "application/javascript"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "amazon"], ["byte_size", 13], ["checksum", "XY+qICmXk3H4sx9RJIwiMA=="], ["created_at", "2022-08-30 21:06:55.029049"]]
  ↳ app/models/property.rb:22:in `make_js_file'
```

I thought maybe where I run the attach method might affect it so I tried adding it in the model, controller, and tested in the console and I get the same result.

I also tried using File, Temfile, and StringIO but get the same result.

Here is an example

```rb
    dir = Rails.root.join("tmp/files")

    file = File.open("#{dir}/#{self.id}.js", "w") { |f| f.write "function(){};" }

    self.js_file.attach(
      io: File.open("#{dir}/#{self.id}.js"),
      filename: "#{self.id}.js",
      content_type: 'application/javascript'
    )
```

Not sure what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. It seems like adding it in the model with a callback created a recursive loop when the attach method is applied to the model. Better to leave out of the model